# jQuery element variable doesn't seem to be accessible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

So I get a set of form elements that I want to extract the values from, by using

```
var inputs = $("input.row_2");
inputs[0].val()
```

When I run this, I get told that val is not a valid method.

What am I doing wrong?

Should be an easy one..
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`inputs[0]` returns you the DOM element, so `inputs[0].value` will have what you want.

You can also use `inputs.eq(0).val()` which will never complain that `inputs[0]` is undefined if there are no matches.

[`.eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq) returns a jQuery object (not DOM) as opposed to [`.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get) which is also what you will get from using `[0]`

Answer (score 0):

A jQUery object behaves like an array of DOM elements.
Therefore, `inputs[0]` returns the raw DOM element, not a jQuery wrapper.
Since raw DOM elements do not have a `val()` method, you're getting an error.

To call jQuery methods on a specific element, you should call the [`eq()` method](http://api.jquery.com/eq/), like this:

```
inputs.eq(0).val();
```

In your case, you can also simply get the `value` property from the raw DOM element, like this:

```
inputs[0].value
```

Note, however, that this will not behave like jQuery's `val()` for `<select>` elements.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input.row_2').first().val();
```